# MFC DLL: class object value is not persisting throughout the exported call

Tags: dll, mfc, export

I have written MFC dll having 3 methods are exported. I have declared class object as global and initialized it in first method then second and third method use and process it.
Issue is that class obeject's value is not getting persisting throughout the file. when second or third method gets call from C# client application, class 
object value is getting NULL.

Could anybody tell me why this is happening! I have tried this same scnaerio in another application but this issue is not reproduced.

Code:
Interface File:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

using namespace nsAnalyzer;
static CWindowsAnalyzer *pWindowsAnalyzer = NULL;

extern "C" DLLEXPORT void Init( const wchar_t       *sCurrentUserDataDir,
                                const wchar_t       *sMachineName,
                                const wchar_t       *sMacId )
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
    try
    {
        nsAnalyzer::CWindowsAnalyzer *pWindowsAnalyzer = new CWindowsAnalyzer(  CString(sCurrentUserDataDir),
                                                                                CString(sMachineName),
                                                                                CString(sMacId) );

        if(pWindowsAnalyzer)
        {
            pWindowsAnalyzer->Init();
        }
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        cout<<"Error: Exception occured in Init: "<<e.what()<<endl;
    }
}

extern "C" DLLEXPORT bool Analyze()
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
    bool bResult = false;

    try
    {
        if(pWindowsAnalyzer->ConsolidateRawActivities())
        {
            cout<<"ConsolidateRawActivities succeed"<<endl;
            bResult = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"ConsolidateRawActivities failed"<<endl;
            bResult = false;
        }
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        cout<<"Error: Exception occured in Analyze: "<<e.what()<<endl;
    }

    return bResult;
}

extern "C" DLLEXPORT void Dispose()
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
    try
    {
        // Disponse windows analyzer
        if(pWindowsAnalyzer)
        {
            delete pWindowsAnalyzer;
        }

        // Dispose Logger
        CLogger::DisposeInstance();
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        cout<<"Error: Exception occured in Dispose: "<<e.what()<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are declaring `pWindowsAnalyzer` as static which is right, but then declaring another locally scoped instance inside the `Init()` function. I would suggest removing `nsAnalyzer::CWindowsAnalyzer *` from the try block so that you are referencing the static instance.

Comment: @user1793036: Thanks a lot user1793036!! You are right, Its my mistake that I was creating another local object within Init(). Thanks again!!